# Using checkboxes to filter data from a db in React.js/Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, checkbox, async-await

I'm working on a web app in React.js which will have a main panel that displays items, and a side panel with checkboxes to filter the items. I'm currently attempting to pass the current set of selected checkboxes back to the parent page - once it's there I can worry about pushing it through to the main display. For now I'm hoping to just display how many boxes are checked, so I know that something is getting through.

I looked at [Filtering with checkboxes in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74584926/filtering-with-checkboxes-in-react) and got a rough sense of `useState`, but it doesn't seem to be working for me - I *believe* the issue I'm hitting is that my DB fetch has to be in an async Component, but then the state doesn't get updated when I hit the checkbox, and I don't know how to resolve this.

Here's my code:

```
'use client'

import { fetchDesignKeywords } from '@/app/lib/data'; /* returns an Array of 2-element arrays */
import { useState } from 'react';

function KeywordFilterControl(props) {
    return(
        <ul className="w-[180px] truncate">
            {props.dks.map(keyword => {
                return(
                    <div key={keyword[0]}>
                        <label className="form-check-label" key={keyword[0]}>
                            <input className="form-check-input mr-2" id={keyword[0]} type="checkbox"
                                onChange={e => props.updateFilters(e.target.checked, keyword[0])}></input>
                            {keyword[0]} ({keyword[1]})
                        </label>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </ul>
    );
}

export default async function Page() {
    let [categoryFilters, setCategoryFilters] = useState(new Set());

    const dks = await fetchDesignKeywords()
    function updateFilters(checked, categoryFilter) {
        console.log(categoryFilter)
        if (checked)
          setCategoryFilters((prev) => new Set(prev).add(categoryFilter));
        if (!checked)
          setCategoryFilters((prev) => {
            const next = new Set(prev);
            next.delete(categoryFilter);
            return next;
          });
      }
    return (
        <div>
            
            <div className="flex flex-row">
                <KeywordFilterControl 
                    updateFilters={updateFilters}
                    dks={dks}/>
                <p>Selected: {categoryFilters.size}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

What I'm hoping for is the `console.log(categoryFilter)` to log something when I click a checkbox, and for the `<p>Selected: {categoryFilters.size}</p>` to update the count. Neither of these is happening - nothing shows up in the console log, and the count remains at 0.

I have tried moving the `const dks = await fetchDesignKeywords()` into the `KeywordFilterControl` function and making that async instead, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

How do I make this work?

EDIT:
Adding a `console.log(keyword);` statement in the map function is printing the full list of keywords to my console.

Comment: Can you try log the keyword  ` console.log(keyword);` inside map function and update the data you receive in the `keyword`?

Answer (score 0):

The **fetchDesignKeywords** operation is asynchronous, and calling it directly in the component body can lead to unpredictable behavior, as React components are synchronous by nature.

Instead use **useEffect** hook for performing this operation as this is a common pattern to handle asynchronous operations in React components.

Secondly, in a React component, if a value is expected to change over time or trigger re-renders, it's a good practice to store it in the component's state. So, it's better to use **useState** for storing the data being returned from **fetchDesignKeywords**. Below is the updated code for your reference.

Please Note following changes in the code:

- **Page component is now not more async component**
- **New state has been added**
- **useEffect is used for async operation**

```js
'use client'

import { fetchDesignKeywords } from '@/app/lib/data';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function KeywordFilterControl(props) {
    return (
        <ul className="w-[180px] truncate">
            {props.dks.map(keyword => (
                <div key={keyword[0]}>
                    <label className="form-check-label" key={keyword[0]}>
                        <input
                            className="form-check-input mr-2"
                            id={keyword[0]}
                            type="checkbox"
                            onChange={e => props.updateFilters(e.target.checked, keyword[0])}
                        ></input>
                        {keyword[0]} ({keyword[1]})
                    </label>
                </div>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
}

export default function Page() {
    const [categoryFilters, setCategoryFilters] = useState(new Set());

    // declaring a new State for storing result of fetchDesignKeywords()
    const [dks, setDks] = useState([]);

    // using useEffect for performing async operation call

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const data = await fetchDesignKeywords();
                setDks(data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []); 

    function updateFilters(checked, categoryFilter) {
        console.log(categoryFilter)
        if (checked)
            setCategoryFilters((prev) => new Set(prev).add(categoryFilter));
        if (!checked)
            setCategoryFilters((prev) => {
                const next = new Set(prev);
                next.delete(categoryFilter);
                return next;
            });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="flex flex-row">
                <KeywordFilterControl
                    updateFilters={updateFilters}
                    dks={dks} />
                <p>Selected: {categoryFilters.size}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This is not working as-is - nothing shows up on the page for KeywordFilterControl, and checking `dks` after the `useEffect` shows it's empty. If I give it an initial value `const [dks, setDks] = useState([['test',0]);`, the initial value and checkbox are rendered, and the checkbox does seem to be hitting the state correctly. But we're not successfully getting the data.

Comment: Have you tried checking the developer console whether the network request is successful or not?

Comment: I'm seeing 2 errors, `Database Error: VercelPostgresError: VercelPostgresError - 'missing_connection_string': You did not supply a 'connectionString' and no 'POSTGRES_URL' env var was found.` and `Error fetching data: Error: Failed to fetch design keywords.` 

With my own code I get those same errors... but the full list of keywords populates.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing:

- Moved `KeywordFilterControl` and the handler function to a separate file so I could keep the 'use client' hooks there.
- used `useSearchParams` in the filter control and `searchParams` in `Page` to put my selected keywords.

```
export default function KeywordFilterControl(props) {
    const searchParams = useSearchParams();
    const pathname = usePathname();
    const { replace } = useRouter();

    function handleCheck(checked, term) {
        const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams)
        if(checked && !params.has('keywords')) {
            params.set('keywords',','.concat(term,','))
        } else if (checked) {
            params.set('keywords',params.get('keywords')?.concat(',',term,','));
        } else {
            params.set('keywords',params.get('keywords')?.replace(','.concat(term,','),''));
        }
        replace(`${pathname}?${params.toString()}`);

      }

    return(
        <ul className="w-[180px] truncate">
            {props.dks.map(keyword => {
                return(
                    <div key={keyword[0]}>
                        <label className="form-check-label" key={keyword[0]}>
                            <input 
                                className="form-check-input mr-2" 
                                id={keyword[0]} 
                                type="checkbox"
                                onChange={e => handleCheck(e.target.checked, keyword[0])}
                                defaultChecked={searchParams.get('keywords')?.includes(keyword[0])}
                                ></input>
                            {keyword[0]} ({keyword[1]})
                        </label>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </ul>
    );
}
```